# Installed modules not displayed for editor user role Prestashop 1.6.1.11

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a user role called Editor, allow show/add/edit of modules and services for them, but when I log in with that role, uninstalled modules are listed only.
I set filter to Installed modules, but no results in the list.

How can I list installed/enabled modules for the new Editor role?

Comment: Hi, can you send a capture to the configuration of the Editor role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You did not selected the module's permission in Editor's permission please check the screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ09E.jpg) you will get. Just select View and it will show you all modules in that role. Thanks